# ¿Qué está mal en este query de SQLite? (Android)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

He buscado con la opción de "Debug" el error en mi aplicación, al parecer está en un comando de SQLite que estoy tratando de ejecutar:

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = " + usuario, null);
```

He borrado la sentencia **"WHERE usuario = " + usuario"** y al parecer eso funcionó, pero es necesario tenerla...
El valor de la variable **usuario** es "Miguel" (Un string), por lo que he descartado la posibilidad de que el comando no funcione por falta de datos, a la vez que SÍ existe dicho usuario en la base de datos.

Este es el código del método que estoy usando:

```
public void LeerAvatarBD() {
    //Prepara la BD
    com.example.apk.sql.ReadApp ra = new com.example.apk.sql.ReadApp(this, "ReadApp", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase ra_bd = ra.getWritableDatabase();

    //Busca los datos en la BD
    Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = " + usuario, null);

    //Inserta los datos leidos en las variables
    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
        piel = fila.getInt(1);
        cara = fila.getInt(2);
        cabello = fila.getInt(3);
        ropa = fila.getInt(4);
        accesorio = fila.getInt(4);
    } else {
        CrearUsuarioBD();
        LeerAvatarBD();
    }

    //Cierra la conexión con la BD
    ra_bd.close();
}
```

Y este es el código de la clase para conectarme a la base de datos:

```
package com.example.apk.sql;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class ReadApp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public ReadApp(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase ReadApp) {
    ReadApp.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Avatar(usuario text, piel int, cara int, cabello int, ropa int, accesorio int)");
    ReadApp.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Progreso(nivel int, actividades int)");
    ReadApp.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Cuentas(usuario text, contraseña text, codigo int, rango int, escuela text, clave_cct text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

Comment: Como usuario es de tipo .text osea Cadena String... entonces debe de llevar ' '.... Intenta esto y me dices si te funciono.
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = '" + usuario+"' ", null);

Comment: Hola Miguel , Que problema se muestra en el LogCat después de realizar el cambio?

Comment: No hay nada que especifique qué ha sucedido, simplemente sale que hay un error en la línea de código donde se encuentra el query

Comment: cuando pasas un valor tipo string o double y otros debes usar comillas en el string. como indica @JesusDanielVazquezLorenzo   usuario = '" + usuario+"' "

Comment: Si no lo has resuelto sube una foto de el error que te arroja.

Comment: En tu código no muestras de donde sale la variable `usuario`, si eso no es un String o viene nulo puede que no obtengas el resultado que esperas. Podrás subir esa parte?

Comment: Hola Miguel, corrige el error del indice para obtener el valor del campo "accesorio". Si continuas con problemas indica cual es el error que se muestra en el LogCat? es importante agregues o comentes que error se muestra tal vez el problema ahora se encuentra en otra parte del código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Parecía ser que la tabla en la base de datos no existía, no arrojaba ningún error relacionado con eso por lo que era difícil saberlo. Tuve que mover la línea de código que crea la tabla al método update y cambiar la versión en mi activity.

Answer (score 7):

Es un error comun, esta es la estructura de tu tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Avatar(usuario text, piel int, cara int, cabello int, ropa int, accesorio int)
```

recuerda que si el campo usuario almacena datos tipo `TEXT` como en este caso `usuario`,  debes agregar comillas para indicar que el valor es una cadena de texto, realizalo de esta forma:

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = '" + usuario + "'", null);
```

y no olvides corregir un error al obtener los valores del cursor, el valor del campo `accesorio` debe tener el indice 5 y no el 4:

```
   ...
   ...
   //Inserta los datos leidos en las variables
    if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
        piel = fila.getInt(1);
        cara = fila.getInt(2);
        cabello = fila.getInt(3);
        ropa = fila.getInt(4);
        accesorio = fila.getInt(5);//fila.getInt(4);
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: mmmm... ya le había respondido eso en un comentario...

Comment: Listo, ya lo intenté, sin embargo sigue sin funcionar.
`Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar  WHERE usuario = '" + usuario + "'", null);`

Comment: Cual es el error que se muestra? es importante agregues o comentes que error se muestra , puedes revisar el LogCat para mas detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Como usuario es de tipo `.text` osea Cadena String... entonces debe de llevar `''`.... Intenta esto y me dices si te funciono.

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = '" + usuario+"'", null);
```

Si "usuario" es el nombre de un **Combobox** o un **Label** Agregale .text de esta manera:

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = '" + usuario.text +"'", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Has probado a usar una ["prepared statement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Así te quedaría:

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = ?", new String[] {usuario});
```

Protección automática contra sql-injection.

Answer (score -3):

Falta saber de donde viene el valor del parámetro **+usuario+**, yo utilizaría un nombre diferente al del campo usuario por ej. user y o si viene de un campo de texto como lo dijo un compañero anterior puedes colocarlo. prueba de esta forma y comentas.

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = '+usuario.text+'", null);
```

si no te funciona así entonces;

```
Cursor fila = ra_bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = " +' usuario', null);
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Avatar WHERE usuario = " +' usuario' esto le marcaría un error ya que no puedes poner comillas simples de esa manera porque esta haciendo una consulta a la Base de Datos y lo que respondiste ya están en Respuestas anteriores mi Estimado.

Comment: Ok, amigo Jesus Daniel, lo que se me ocurre para resolver este caso, es pedirle a Miguel Cliche que comparta el codigo para testearlo mas detalladamente inclusive con una interfaz para probarlo con datos